# Babel prefixes variables with underscore in specific scenerio

Tags: javascript, babeljs

This is the simplest I could make it.

Orignal

```
var a = {
    a: function() {
        a.b;
    }
};
```

after `babel js -d lib --presets es2015`

```
"use strict";

var _a = {
    a: function a() {
        _a.b;
    }
};
```

It changes a global variable which messes up my already written code that uses it extensively. Note that it only happens if the parent and child have same name and if I try to access any of parent's properties form within child.

If the names are not the same (a) or if I don't access any of the root object's properties (a.b) the underscore isn't added.

I also know that the underscore only comes on with the es2015 preset but that makes sense since those are the only plugins I have.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I stop it from adding that underscore? All of my code uses that global variable. It's important that it doesn't change it's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel assumes that the top-level scope of a file is the module scope, not the global scope, so renaming the variable is safe. If you want something to be global, you'd be better off being explicit about it, e.g.

```
var a = {
```

to one of

```
global.a = {
window.a = {
```

Comment: This was it! Thanks! :)

Comment: I have seen cases that make me question this logic. Most have to do with angular's dependency injection logic. Angular looks explicitly at function arguments, so sometimes those need to be excluded from whatever logic creates the underscores. Do you know if there is any option for including or excluding underscores? I'm not even sure which exact plugin does this.

Comment: You'd potentially be interested in https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate Unfortunately the behavior you are seeing is unavoidable. Renaming things is required in some cases to create valid ES6 functionality. The `.toString` behavior Angular  relies on is not something guaranteed in the ECMAScript spec, it was a poor choice on their part to rely on it.

Comment: Right now I use gulp-ng-annotate. I tried that plugin but it did not work, I forget why. I might try it again at some point. I agree that was a bad decision, but it is still too bad that that behavior is unavoidable because angular is so popular, and version 1 is still popular. We will hopefully be switching to React soon, but you know, actual work trumps learning about cool new frameworks.